# Como expandir um array_shift além da quantidade de índices?

Tags: php, array

Estou com uma dúvida. Coloco o código logo abaixo antes iniciar um `while` mas dentro do loop, ao chamar o `array_shift($cores)`, ele aplica as classes enquanto loop é `<=` que a quantidade de índices, ou seja, no `índice 4` ele já não aplica mais as classes.

Se eu colocar então 10 itens dentro do loop, 6 vão ficar sem classe alguma provavelmente porque está instrução coloca índice sem repeti-lo.

```
$cores = ["primary", "secondary", "tertiary", "quaternary"];
shuffle($cores);
```

**LOOP**

```
if ( $empr->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $empr->have_posts() ) { $empr->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="team-item <?php echo array_shift($cores); ?>"> ...
```

Pergunta: Como continuar aplicando as classes? Um exemplo pode ser visualizado ***[aqui](http://builders.axitech.com.br/another)*** na sessão ***OUTROS EMPREENDIMENTOS***.

Comment: Talvez usar o `rand()` e jogar o retorno como index do array pode ser uma solução, assim nenhum elemento array é removida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Usando array_shift

Você pode rotacionar o *array* assim:

```
array_push( $cores, array_shift($cores) );
```

Aplicado ao código:

```
if ( $empr->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $empr->have_posts() ) {
        $empr->the_post();
        echo '<div class="team-item ' . $cores[0] . '">';
        array_push( $cores, array_shift($cores) );
        ...
```

**Explicação:**

Quando você dá um `array_shift` em `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }`, a função vai retornar `1`, e ao mesmo tempo o array vai virar `{ 2, 3, 4 }`.

Em seguida, damos um `array_push`, pegando o `1` retornado, e adicionando ao final do mesmo *array*. Como o *array* havia sido encurtado para `{ 2, 3, 4 }`, ao adicionarmos o `1` no final ele vira `{ 2, 3, 4, 1 }`, e assim sucessivamente: `{ 3, 4, 1, 2 }`, `{ 4, 1, 2, 3 }`, `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }` ...

### Alternativa com módulo

Segue uma alternativa que eu acho até mais enxuta do que com `array_shift`.

```
$i = 0;
if ( $empr->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $empr->have_posts() ) { $empr->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="team-item <?php echo $cores[$i++ % 4]; ?>"> ...
```

Comment: Boa dica, acredito que a sua resposta falta o indice do array array_push($cores[0],array_shift($cores)), mas verifica a utilização com o pop também que é melhor.

Comment: @Guerra push e pop vão trabalhar na mesma "ponta" do array. O shift retorna um ítem só, e ao mesmo tempo remove ele da array. então na hora do push a array já vai estar mais curta, e ser adicionado ao final. Se puser índice, vai ficar com 2 ítens só. Vou atualizar a resposta explicando isso.

Comment: Bem dito, mas pelo o que vi o pop por realizar no final do array não necessita atualizar o indicie de todas as ocorrencias.

Comment: @Guerra eu só respondi com array_shift pq tava na pergunta, mas acho que a 2a solução que eu pus é um bocado mais técnica do que a 1a, pra falar a verdade. É que eu também gosto da idéia de explicar as funções, pra ajudar o pessoal aprender o funcionamento interno delas, pra usar pra outras coisas também.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se eu entendi direito, mas o array_shift remove o primeiro item certo?

Imagino que algo assim vá resolver seu problema:

```
$cores = ["primary", "secondary", "tertiary", "quaternary"];
shuffle($cores);
$tmp = null;

if ( $empr->have_posts() ) {
while ( $empr->have_posts() ) { $empr->the_post(); ?>
    $tmp = is_null($tmp) ? $cores : $tmp;
    <div class="team-item <?php echo array_shift($tmp); ?>"> ...
```

Dei uma estudada aqui, e acredito que o array_pop é mais indicado pois não  necessita que atualize o indice do array. Ficaria assim (mudei o ternario tb pra ver se vai):

```
$cores = ["primary", "secondary", "tertiary", "quaternary"];
shuffle($cores);
$tmp = null;

if ( $empr->have_posts() ) {
while ( $empr->have_posts() ) { $empr->the_post(); ?>
    $tmp = !$tmp ? $cores : $tmp;
    <div class="team-item <?php echo array_pop($tmp); ?>"> ..
```

O array_pop faz a mesma coisa que o shift porém no ultimo elemento do array, como você não faz questão da ordem imagino que vá servir igual, porém com melhoria de performace.

Comment: Que estanho @Guerra continua não retornando as classes.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com uma melhor, verifique se está usando o $tmp no echo